# what is object Promise and object Object? selenium+JavaScript

Tags: javascript, selenium

I want to get a Team Name etc...I use selenium and Javascript.
What I want is get webpage and today's team name.

but the console.log said

```
[NBA][object Promise]([object Object]) -vs- [object Object]([object Object])    [object Object]    [object Object
```

What is object Promise and object Object?
my code is

```
let chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');

let By = webdriver.By;
let Builder = webdriver.Builder;
let until = webdriver.until;
let Key = webdriver.Key;

let map = webdriver.promise.map;

(async () => {
    try {
             var driver = await new webdriver.Builder()
                    .withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome())
                    .setChromeService(new chrome.ServiceBuilder(
                    "C:\\ScoreAndOdds\\JS\\chromedriver.exe")).build();

                    await driver.get("https://www.scoresandodds.com/nba");
                    //await driver.get("https://www.scoresandodds.com/mlb");
                    await driver.sleep(2500);

                    var elements = await driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='event-card']"));
                    var vals = await map(elements, element => element.getAttribute('id')).then();
                    var id =[];
                    //vals.forEach(val => console.log(val));
                    vals.forEach(val => id.push(val));
                    console.log("----");
                    console.log(id);
                    //console.log(id[1]);


                    driver.findElement(By.xpath('/html/body/footer/div[3]/div/div/a[2]')).click();

                    await driver.sleep(2500);
                    const home = driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id="nba.18032"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/div/span[2]/span[1]/span'));
                    const homeN = driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id="nba.18032"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/div/span[2]/span[2]/a/span'));
                    const away = driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id="nba.18032"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/div/span[2]/span[1]/span'));
                    const awayN = driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id="nba.18032"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/div/span[2]/span[2]/a/span'));
                    const playtime = driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id="nba.18032"]/table/thead/tr/th[1]/span[2]'));
                    const tv= driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id="nba.18032"]/table/thead/tr/th[1]/span[2]'));
                    await driver.sleep(2500);
                    console.log("[NBA]" + home + "(" + homeN + ")" +" -vs- " + away + "(" + awayN + ")" + "    " + playtime + "    " + tv + "\n\n\n");
```

Would somebody please teach me how I can get Team name?

Answer (score 0):

I got this code.

```
                    let home = await driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id="nba.18035"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/div/span[2]/span[1]/span')).getText();

console.log(home);
```